# Cannot apply JSON Filter to Native American Reservations in Google Maps

Tags: json, google-maps

-- I am making a very simple map from Google 3.0 and when I strip down the map.  I am left with white shapes in North America that match up to Native American reservation.  I cannot separate them from the higher level "administrative" and they do not fall under country, province, locality, neighborhood or land parcel.

```
 "featureType": "administrative", 
 "elementType": "geometry", 
 "stylers": [ { "visibility": "off"} ]
```

Comment: Not enough information. Google 3.0? What is this code from? Where are you even referencing "Native American Reservations"?

Comment: Please state your question more clearly. It's also useful to mention exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: or points of interest

Answer (score 5):

I've experienced a similar issue and got around it by setting the color of all geometry elements to be the same as the color of the landscape geometry element:

```
styles: [
  {
    'featureType': 'all',
    'elementType': 'geometry',
    'stylers': [{
      'color': '#444444'
    }, {
      'visibility': 'on'
    }]
  },
  {
    'featureType': 'landscape',
    'elementType': 'geometry',
    'stylers': [{
      'color': '#444444'
    }, {
      'visibility': 'on'
    }]
  },
]
```

Assume that in the above example #444444 is the land color. I stumbled upon this fix by analysing the JSON code of maps on [SnazzyMaps](https://snazzymaps.com/), but I also found the [Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) helpful for figuring out which settings applied to which map elements.

As an aside, I found that the above code also fixed some issues I was experience where certain buildings appeared with the default Google Maps styles when zoomed right in (i.e. zoom level of 16-18).

The code above changed their color so that it was the same as everything else but there were some pesky little icons that appeared for public toilets, lifts and disabled access, etc. In order to remove them I used the following additional code:

```
styles: [
  {
    'featureType': 'all',
    'elementType': 'labels.icon',
    'stylers': [{
      'visibility': 'off'
    }]
  }
]
```

I realise this question is old but hopefully my answer helps other people in future.